# How to move a div with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am definitely new to Javascript.My goal is to build two divs and animate the child just by using Javascript.But there is some kind of problem in my function, and despite this being a trivial task I couldn’t find anything.

So, these are my buttons and my divs(I’m just trying to figure out how the start button works, then I am going to deal with the others

```
//create elements
const start = document.createElement('button');
const reset = document.createElement('button');
const stop = document.createElement('button');



const parent = document.createElement("div");
const child= document.createElement("div");
document.body.append(parent);
parent.append(child);
document.body.append(start);
document.body.append(reset);
document.body.append(stop);

// style 
parent.style.width = "200px";
parent.style.height = "200px";

child.style.width = "20px";
child.style.height = "20px";


child.style.background = "green"
parent.style.background  = "red";

start.innerHTML = "start";
reset.innerHTML = "reset";
stop.innerHTML = "stop";
```

and this is my useless function which doesn’t look right

```
/functions and listeners
var g =setInterval(move(),2000);
function move(){
    var pos = 0;
    if (pos == 200) {
        clearInterval(g);
    }
    else {
        pos++;
        child.style.top = pos + "px";
        child.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
}
start.addEventListener("click",move());
```

any kind of tip or advice is appreciated =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have several problems:**

- The `pos` variable needs to be declared outside of the function that
  uses it so that its value won't be lost when the function runs and
  then can be used when the function runs additional times.
- The start button's click event handler should be where the interval
  timer is started, otherwise it begins immediately.
- Both [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) take
  function ***references*** - - you do not ***invoke*** a function in
  their arguments (unless that function returns a function and that
  returned function is what you want to reference). So, neither should
  have `()` after the function name.
- Your parent and child elements need to be positioned so that they are
  not in the normal document flow, otherwise setting a `top` or `left`
  CSS property won't do anything.
- Don't use `.innerHTML` when you aren't working with HTML strings as
  `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications. When you just
  have text to work with, use `.textContent`.

See other comments inline:

```js
//create elements
const start = document.createElement('button');
const reset = document.createElement('button');
const stop = document.createElement('button');

const parent = document.createElement("div");
const child= document.createElement("div");
document.body.append(parent);
parent.append(child);
document.body.append(start);
document.body.append(reset);
document.body.append(stop);

/* Use CSS classes instead of inline styles */
parent.classList.add("parent");
child.classList.add("child");

start.textContent = "start";
reset.textContent = "reset";
stop.textContent = "stop";

//functions and listeners
var timer = null;
var pos = 0;
function move(){
  // Since it's the top and left of the child that are being set, we
  // need to subtract the width of the box from the size of the parent
  // so that the child doesn't end with its top and left outside of the
  // parent.
  if (pos == 180) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  } else {
    pos++;
    child.style.top = pos + "px";
    child.style.left = pos + "px";
  }
}
start.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // The timer should start when the button is clicked
  timer = setInterval(move,20);
});

reset.addEventListener("click", function() {    
  clearInterval(timer); // Stop the timer so motion stops
  pos = 0;     
  child.style.top = pos+ "px";     
  child.style.left = pos + "px";      
});
```

```css
/* The child needs to be taken out of the normal document flow so it can be
   explicitly positioned, but we want it to be relative to the parent it is
   inside of, so the parent also has to be positioned explicitly.  */
.parent { position:relative; width: 200px; height:200px; background-color:red; }
.child { position:relative; width: 20px; height:20px; background-color:green; }
```

Comment: one last quick question: my reset button works fine, but when I click it, the square starts running down automatically.How can I just reset the position and then make the square start only when I press the start button? This is my reset button `reset.addEventListener("click", function() {
    pos = 0;
    child.style.top = pos+ "px";
    child.style.left = pos + "px";
    
}) `

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer to address your last question, which really just needs the addition of `clearInterval(timer);` so that the motion stops. Please consider marking this as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top left of the answer.